# toggle childview in listview

Tags: android, listview

I have listview layout(shown below) with Image-button invisible by default and made  visible when users click the listrow item.

```
----------------------------------
|TextView          | ImageButton |
----------------------------------


 mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

 view.setSelected(true);
 ImageButton btnChild = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.playbtn);
     btnChild.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
    });
```

I want to set the Imagebutton invisible while user selects different list item.

Comment: can you post your full code of listview adapter !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store a reference to latest selected item and change your code like this:

```
View latestSelected;
.
.
.
mylist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {

        view.setSelected(true);
        ImageButton btnChild = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.playbtn);
        btnChild.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (latestSelected != null){
            ImageButton btnChild1 = (ImageButton)latestSelected.findViewById(R.id.playbtn);
            btnChild1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        latestSelected = view;
    }
});
```